# set background image for on/off position on switch button in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am working on xamarin forms.
I want to use ON/OFF button. Instead of ON/OFF text, I want IN/OUT. Can anyone suggest me any matched UI for this one.

Comment: Please don't use signatures or taglines in your posts. Every post is already "signed" with your user card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using CheckBox with image for this issue.